# How to make a SimpleProperty inform listeners on the first set?

Tags: java, javafx, properties, listener

When I write this:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;

SimpleBooleanProperty foo = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
foo.addListener(
    new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(
             ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
             Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue
        ) {
            System.out.println(oldValue + " " + newValue);                    
        }
    }
);
foo.set(false);
foo.set(true);
```

The output is

```
false true
```

However, if I change the last two lines to

```
foo.set(true);
foo.set(false);
```

The output is

```
false true
true false
```

I find this rather inconsistent. How can I ensure that the Listener is always notified on the first `set` ?

... or is it common sense that the listener should explicitly call `foo.get()` to get the initial value and then be informed only on changes? In that case I still wouldn't know how to distinguish between the default `false` and a `false` that has been set before the listener registered.

Comment: Michael’s answer is correct.  It’s called a *change listener* because it’s only triggered when the value actually changes.

Comment: why do you want that? Sounds like a suboptimal setup ...

Comment: @kleopatra why do you think it is suboptimal?

Comment: probability ;) you know the value when registering, so why would you want the property to go illegal and fire something with old== new? Cant think of a context where that's important

Comment: @kleopatra I think what I actually want is a `ActionListener` the gets notified each time the value gets set. And I got confused because at the same time I do need the `ChangeListener` that gets notified on changes. I think I will write an answer that maybe clarifies what I was after

Comment: .. good idea :)

Comment: @kleopatra done. anyhow the given answer did already help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly consistent.

The problem is that `SimpleBooleanProperty` is **already initialised to false**. When you call `foo.set(false)` first then the value hasn't actually changed, so the listener is not called.

When you call `foo.set(true)` first then the value changes twice (false -> true -> false) which invokes the listener twice.

If you want the initial value to be true, use [the constructor which takes a boolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleBooleanProperty.html#SimpleBooleanProperty-boolean-).

---

If you want to fire an event when attaching the listener, you could extend `SimpleBooleanProperty` quite easily, though it's not clear to me what you would use for the old value (null, I guess?):

```
class FireWhenAttachBooleanProperty extends SimpleBooleanProperty
{
    @Override
    public void addListener(ChangeListener<? super Boolean> listener)
    {
        super.addListener(listener);
        listener.changed(this, null, getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: the only valid old value is ... the old value ;)

Comment: @kleopatra You can *almost* solve that problem by having `FireWhenAttachBooleanProperty` listen to itself... I feel like a mad scientist

Comment: hmm .. will remove my first comment because thinking about it, I'm not entirely certain ;) Not sure if oldvalue == newValue is a valid notification - probably not, because the property guarantees to fire only if both are different

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it wasnt clear from the question (if it was then I guess I didnt have to ask the question ;). My mistake was that I actually want to react on two different things: One kind of listener should be notified each time the value is set, and a different kind of listener only when the value is changed. So I actually need something like this:

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;

class Foo {
    private SimpleBooleanProperty foo = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private ArrayList<EventHandler> listener = new ArrayList<>();
    public void set(Boolean value) {
        foo.set(value);
        ActionEvent e = new ActionEvent();
        for(EventHandler l : listener) l.handle(e);
    }
    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener<Boolean> x) { 
        foo.addListener(x); 
    }
    public void addEventHandler(EventHandler a){
        listener.add(a);
    }
}
```

Such that I can write this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                        Boolean oldValue, 
                        Boolean newValue) {
        System.out.println("value changed");                
    }            
});
foo.addEventHandler(new EventHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        System.out.println("value was set");
    }            
});        
foo.set(false);
```

where even thought the value does not change, the eventhandler is notified.